# ngModelChange only on blur if there was change

Tags: angular

I want to only call updateDetail() on the blur event and only if the model has changed. So right now if the user blurs (tabs) out of the input box without making a change it will call updateDetail() and perform unnecessary calculations. Can someone please remove my ignorance?

```
<input type="text" (ngModelChange)="updateDetail(d)" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" name='detail-monthly-payment'
                            [(ngModel)]="d.periodPayment" />
```

Comment: Just found this, I will see if this helps: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20259

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use just `(change)` in place of `(ngModelChange)`

---

I think, This issue is no more with Angular5, Please check

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelchange-blur)**

Comment: If it is just that easy I will be upset with myself. Let me try

Comment: I appreciate your help most profusely sir. That worked and was so obvious I had to slap my head. I would blame my lack of coffee at 6:38 AM in the morning, but that would be to easy an excuse. That worked perfectly and I can cross it off my to do list. I give you joy.

Comment: @Maccurt, My pleasure sir , please do accept and upvote the answer, if works :) .

Comment: Is there documentation about this. In documentation I can find about `(ngModelChange)` only but nothing about `(change)`

Comment: @nest , you can't find it as those events are not custom made by angular like `ngModelChange` , its javascripts default event.

Comment: I have the same question, but I don'e see you used `(change)` in your demo. Where?

Answer (score 0):

check on your function if exist any changes:

```
updateDetail(event:any){
 if(this.d.periodPayment == event)
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just store the previous value and compare it with the new one in `updateDetail(d)` and only do the calculation when they differ.

I don't think using `(change)="..."` together with `ngModel` is a good idea. `d.periodPayment` won't contain the new value yet when `updateDetail()` is called.

Comment: How do you store the previous value? Using `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: Create field (variable) in the component and every time `updateDetail(d)` is called check if they are different and if not update the field with the new value.